# Internal API error

Tags: ios, iphone

Since few days, every time I try to run my app on my iPhone, I get get this error message "There was an internal API error".

**I'm getting this error just with one application only on my iPhone. In fact, there's no problem with the same app on simulator or on my iPad. No problem too with other apps on my iPhone...**

I've tried many things mentioned in those threads:

- ["There was an internal API error." while running an app on any iPhone/iPod-touch device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564392/there-was-an-internal-api-error-while-running-an-app-on-any-iphone-ipod-touch)
- [Xcode 4.4 - There was an internal API error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715909/xcode-4-4-there-was-an-internal-api-error)

like remove/re-run the app, reboot iPhone/mac, clear cache, check plist, check profiles, check build settings, restore iPhone.

I'm using xCode 7.1.1 and iOS 7.1.2

Can someone point me on what I forget to check please ?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide an excerpt of the device logs surround the error, in case there are clues in the details. In Xcode, Window → Devices → your device in the left column, then scroll through the logs.

Comment: "Since few days" So use your version control to go back to _before_ things went wrong, and see what changed! Even better: Why not just make a new project, check that it works, and then slowly migrate your code into it? Don't waste any time worrying about what happened to _this_ project.

Comment: I've already try to check the device's logs too. The problem is that there is nothing, just two line very old.

Comment: :D last iOS version fast on 4s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I rename my project and delete the special character "ç", xCode success to run the app on my iPhone. It might be related to xCode 7, before there was no problem for compiling.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you please tell us how do you rename the project ..... ?

Answer (score 2):

As per my work and research I got a solution. Since I was preparing the build in manual way from product. In that case my appname.app was copying in folder from which I have to create a build, that app was not copied properly and I prepared the build and installed in my device, in that case I got this error.

I again clean the Xcode prepare the build properly and installed it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. The way I solved it was by removing the special characters from the Product Name (in Build Settings) - I had an 'æ'. Indeed, it looks related to Xcode 7, because it used to work on previous versions of Xcode.