# App installation failed - There was an internal API error. (xCode 9.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, internal

A bit of background-information first:

Recently, I needed to go back to an older version of my xcode-App-project. So i checked out a backup-branch and continued from there. The Head-commit of the backup-branch i went too was about 1 month old, and i've had to update my Xcode to 9.0 in the meantime.

I am currently using:

- Swift 3.2
- Xcode 9.1

First of all: I can build my project without any problem. The only warning I get is about the conversion to Swift 4, which I've been recommended not to do until all the external libraries used in my project have a release compatible with Swift 4.

When I now try to run my project after it built successfully, I get the following errors:

When trying to run on my iPhone SE: (iOS 11.1):

> App Installation failed - There was an internal API error.

When trying to run on an iPhone 6s Simulator (iOS 11.0):

> This App was unable to be installed.

I've already tried the following in order to resolve this problem:

- Completely delete the App from my iPhone SE and reinstall it
- Updating to **Swift 4.0**, which then gave me a ton of other errors and made me go back to Swift 3.2
- Checking my podfile and updating my pods via the "pod update" command

Unfortunately I've only recently started programming, my mistake might aswell be something advanced programmers would consider as incredibly trivial. But since I couldn't find a solution after multiple hours of google-search, I had to ask you guys. Thanks for your help already.

Edit: I've now updated my Xcode to the newest version: 9.1.
However, it's still giving me the exact same error.

Comment: xCode was recently updated. Did you update it?

Comment: No, I haven't yet updated from 9.0 to 9.1. But I will go ahead and do so now, thanks. Hopefully this will solve the problem already.

Comment: Alright, I'm done updating now but unfortunately I'm still getting the exact same error..

Comment: Do you have any frameworks in you project?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the Alamofire.framework.
In case that's any useful to know: I'm also using other external libraries, namely "KeychainSwift" and "SwiftyJSON".

Comment: Nothing criminal... Try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857020/unable-to-install-app-in-simulator-xcode-9-beta

Comment: Please use this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659771/internal-api-error/46988249#46988249

Comment: Thanks alot for your answers.
@blyabtroi Your reference helped me in particular. 
I could figure out more or less what the problem was by following the steps shown here:
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/44867510/8873905

For me the issue was, that I deleted one of my Frameworks earlier, so I just went back to my last commit.

Comment: I think I can't yet give you an upvote or something for your answer because I only have 1 Reputation.. how else could I return the favor?